# Calling Const function pointer

Tags: c++, function, c++11, constants

First off I would like to mention that this works with MSVC but not with clang. I am using Clang with c++11.

I have a function pointer:

```
typedef void (*Log) (const char* title, const char* msg, const char* file, int line);
```

I have this struct:

```
 struct FunctionList
    {
    protected:
        static const int kNbrMax = 32;
        FunctionList();
        bool Add(const void* f);
        bool Remove(const void* f);

        const void*     m_functions[kNbrMax];
    };
```

And this class:

```
template<typename T>
struct MessageFunctionList
    : public FunctionList
{
public:
    MessageFunctionList(T defaultFunction)  
    {
        Add(defaultFunction);
    }

    void Call(const char* title,const char* cause,const char* file,int line)
    {
        for (unsigned long i = 0;i < m_nbrUsed;++i)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<T>(m_functions[i])(title,cause,file,line);
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating it like so:

```
static void DefaultLogMessageFunction(const char* title,const char* msg,const char* file,int line)
{

}

MessageFunctionList<Log> functionList(DefaultLogMessageFunction)
```

But I get the compile time error:

> reinterpret_cast from 'const void *' to 'void (*)(const char *, const
>   char *, const char *, int)' casts away qualifiers  for line:
>   reinterpret_cast(m_functions[i])(title,cause,file,line);

So as far as I understand I am trying to cast my const list of functions to a non const value. That is not allowed which makes sense. So I tried the following:

```
const void* funcPtr = m_functions[i];
const T call = reinterpret_cast<const T>(funcPtr);
call(title, cause, file, line);
```

But that does not work either.

This works:

```
void* funcPtr = const_cast<void*>(m_functions[i]);
T call = reinterpret_cast<T>(funcPtr);
call(title,cause,file,line);
```

But I would like to avoid using a const cast. What am I doing wrong? How can I call this const function? Or is it simply not allowed because it does not know if the function being called is a const function or not? Or perhaps it is because my static function is not a member of a class so it can not be declared const?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. I can't tell what you're actually doing.

Comment: What am I missing? What is included that is not necessary? I think I have included everything needed? Do you want a zipped project? I am trying to store a list of function pointers to log functions.

Comment: You're missing an MCVE. I'm looking for a short, self-contained, example that I can see what compile error you're getting and what you're trying to do. All I see are several unconnected code fragments and I do not understand either what you're trying to do or why it's failing.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/RfbrUI It seems to compile fine though which is a problem. I am not sure why my clang compiler is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the function pointers as `const void*`:

```
const void*     m_functions[kNbrMax];
```

And you are *trying* to cast them to `T` and call it using `reinterpret_cast`:

```
reinterpret_cast<T>(m_functions[i])(title,cause,file,line);
```

However, `reinterpret_cast` cannot remove `const` qualifier from a type, therefore, you should first remove the `const` using `const_cast`:

```
reinterpret_cast<T>(const_cast<void*>(m_functions[i]))(title,cause,file,line);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, please note that `const_cast` engenders undefined behavior and is unsafe. So is calling a function pointer returned from `reinterpret_cast` if the original pointer was not actually a `T`.

**Edit:**
You can call a `const` qualified function pointer, however, then the `reinterpret_cast` should contain the `const` qualifier:

```
reinterpret_cast<const T>(m_functions[i])(title,cause,file,line);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I provided that same solution myself at the bottom of my post. I dont understand why I cant store and call a const function. I am trying to avoid const cast.

Comment: I tried that as well figuring it would work but I get the same error. Its weird because online clang compilers seem to compile it without error.

Comment: @marsh, so does online and offline g++ compilers: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccf66094fb802e7d

Comment: Yes that is indeed a problem, I believe it is a custom built version for console development. I guess that people cannot provide support for that when they cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @marsh, I have no idea, however it looks like a compiler problem instead of a language one. Also, as far as I know, it is undefined to cast a function pointer to a `void*`. Why don't you use T directly to store the function pointers, by simply letting the base class go?

Comment: The function pointer type changes, that part was not included in my example. You are right though I think this is a compiler problem that I will have to solve.

Comment: @marsh, the function pointer type can still change, check this one, it is type safe: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6759067d687386a6